# Select statement with output clause doesn't work

Tags: sql

Not getting the value of `@lastupdate`. If removing the `SELECT` statement, then getting the value of `@lastupdate` in codebehind

```
@action int,
@autoid int = NULL,
@datecheck date = NULL,
@lastupdate datetime = '' OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF @action = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @lastupdate = (SELECT reddate FROM lastupdate)
        SELECT * FROM view_mychart WHERE processdate=@datecheck 
    END
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any output parameters are returned after the results set. Make sure you have processed/read the results before trying to access the output parameter.

Comment: con.Open()
            myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If myreader.HasRows Then


                lastupdate.Text = cmd.Parameters("@lastupdate").Value
                myreader.Read()
                myreader.Close()
                lastupdate.Text = cmd.Parameters("@lastupdate").Value
            Else
                lastupdate.Text = cmd.Parameters("@lastupdate").Value.ToString
            End If

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you should be using something along the lines of the following:

```
SELECT @lastupdate = reddate FROM lastupdate
```

Though personally I would probably limit the query as this could take a while depending on database size etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you *need both* - just write both statements

```
IF @action = 1
    BEGIN
        -- are you 1000% sure this only ever returns ONE ROW???
        -- otherwise, you might need to change it somehow....
        SELECT @lastupdate = reddate FROM lastupdate

        SELECT * FROM view_mychart WHERE processdate = @datecheck 
    END
END
```

That should work just fine!